# How to upgrade only two eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Eclipse has its own built-in Java compiler. Because my eclipse is old, there are some bugs in the compiler, which blocks my works currently.

At the beginning, I tried use Help>Check for updates. This fails and upgrade does not continue because of some plugin is installed locally and the failure of checking these local directory results in exit of whole upgrade.

`No repository found at file:/c:/J9%20Development%20Tools/j9dt-update-site/.`

Therefore, is it possible to update only two or three plugins in Eclipse?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To remove the problematic local plugin:**

1. Goto `Help` > `Install New Software`
2. Click on `Available Software Sites`
3. Uncheck the problematic item and click either `Disable` or `Remove`.  Give OK.
4. Try updating

---

In recent versions of Eclipse (like [Luna](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/luna)), you can selectively update the desired plugin.

Just go to `Help` > `Installation Details`

[image]

Select the plugin you want to update, and then click the `Update...` button.

[image]